# How to create a shader for mayonnaise?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, workflow

I'm a beginner in blender and am creating a 3d burger. I do not know how to create the shader for the mayonnaise. I don't know much about materials, so I thought of taking advice here. I tried playing with some basic settings, but I don't know much.

**Q:** How would one create a mayonnaise material for cycles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try something like this - the main "ingredients" that make it distinct are a Transmission Value as well as some Subsurface Scattering to simulate the translucency of mayo. The Noise Texture gives it that lumpy "spread" look:

[image: Mayo]

Comment: I tried this, but instead I am getting solid mayonnaise instead of one like yours.

Comment: Strange - I didn't do anything special -  I mainly just upped those 2 values, as well as lower the roughness.. You can take the transmission and SSS values higher if you want, but if it isn't having an effect, I'm not sure. What is your lighting like? Both those values can be light/angle dependent.

Comment: I have one point lamp, and the edges of the mayonnaise are blue. and nor do i undurtand how to give it a squashed liquid look. I will also try an hdr now.

Comment: Try checking it in cycles,  the solution you provided. And I still don't know how to make it hang down like real mayonnaise.

Comment: You can use the edit link at the bottom of your question to provide more detail and clarify your question, and it'll get bumped back into active questions.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Removing the transmission helps